# HTML Position Issue in Firefox (Works in IE and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have the following code. When I mouse over the “CODE” it should show the div on position 100 X100. It is working fine in IE and Chrome; however the div does not move to the required position in Firefox.  What need to be changed in order to make it working?

Note: I am using the following  code for positioning the div

```
$('#tooltip').css({ left: 100 + "px", top: 100 + "px", position: "absolute" })
```

--Complete Code --

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>

<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css">

    .tooltip

    {

        background-color: Orange;

        position: absolute;

        border-style: solid;

        border-width: 2px;

        border-bottom: solid 2px black;

    }

</style>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">





    function showDiv(batchId, vendorId) {



        tooltip.style.display = "block";

        batch.innerHTML = batchId;

        vendor.innerHTML = vendorId;

        $('#tooltip').css({ left: 100 + "px", top: 100 + "px", position: "absolute" })

    }



</script>

</head>

<body>

<div>

    <div>

        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_grdTooltip" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

            <tr>

                <th scope="col">MainID</th>

                <th scope="col">SecondID</th>

                <th scope="col">CODE</th>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>101</td>

                <td>999999991</td>

                <td onmouseover="showDiv(101,999999991)">55789</td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>

    <div id="tooltip" class="tooltip">

        <table>

            <tr>

                <td>Main Id:</td>

                <td id="batch"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>Second Id:</td>

                <td id="vendor"></td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) for examples like this.  It's good for you for creating a proof of concept AND easier for those trying to understand your issue.  Once you "save", you can paste in a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/6GaEA/1/

The problem (according to firebug) lies in your script.  You reference a variable 'tooltip' that's not defined.  Chrome and IE seem to swallow this error and continue, while firefox chokes and dies.

change this:

```
 function showDiv(batchId, vendorId) {

    tooltip.style.display = "block";

    batch.innerHTML = batchId;

    vendor.innerHTML = vendorId;

    $('#tooltip').css({ left: 100 + "px", top: 100 + "px", position: "absolute" })

}
```

to this:

```
function showDiv(batchId, vendorId) {

    $('#tooltip').css('display',"block");

    $('#batch').html(batchId);

    $('#vendor').html(vendorId);

    $('#tooltip').css({ left: 100 + "px", top: 100 + "px", position: "absolute" })

}
```

edit: I am aware that the jQuery css function is called on $("#tooltip") twice.  I was trying to keep the same flow of the code as much as possible :)

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138108/html-css-flow-layout-issue ?

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141148/css-two-column-div-layout-misaligns-when-zoom-changes

Answer (score 0):

To make "absolute" work as position for your element, parent element must have its position set to relative or absolute.
That is in your case add css "position: relative" to TD which has onmouseover event.

Comment: position: absolute; refers to the first parent who has a position other than static (relative or absolute, not sure of interaction with fixed parent and absolute child).  If no parent is found, the element is positioned relative to the viewport.  So, his code will work, if he wants it positioned to the viewport.

Comment: I guess it should not be positioned in realtion to viewport since it is a tooltip for UI element.

Comment: thats probably true.  There are jquery libraries and other assistances for positioning it relative to a specific element.  http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/ is a pretty good one for tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery CSS method should be used in this way:

```
$("#something").css(propertyName,value);
```

and its better to handle Events in your scripts this way:

```
$("#something").mouseover(function() {
    $("#tooltip").css("display","block");
  });
```

and for positioning an element absolutely its parent should be positioned relatively.

Comment: Lijo's use of .css() is valid.  It allows you to set multiple style properties at once.  But yes, the coded event binding is better than the declarative one.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
            function showDiv(batchId, vendorId) {
                document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('batch').innerHTML = batchId;
               // batch.innerHTML = batchId;
                document.getElementById('vendor').innerHTML = vendorId;
                //vendor.innerHTML = vendorId;
            }

        </script>
```